# Excel evaluation formula false when it should be true

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Trying to create a table in Excel for [Mnemonics Major System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mnemonic_major_system) to practice. Excel is evaluating a formula false when it should be true.

```
=IF(Q2=0,"Z",IF(Q2=1,"T", IF(Q2=2,"N",IF(Q2=3,"M",IF(Q2=4,"R",IF(Q2=5,"L",IF(Q2=6,"J",IF(Q2=7,"K",IF(Q2=8,"F",IF(Q2=9,"P"))))))))))
```

Q2 is filled in by this formula:

```
=MID(O2,1,1)
```

Which references a random set of 4 digit numbers. The error when I evaluate the formula is **"2"=2**

My goal is to convert for numbers to characters in the Major System to letters, and then hide the letters with formatting so I can plug in what I think the answer is and Excel should validate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MID formula returns a string, while your IF is checking for a number. Convert the MID to a number with INT or put quotes in the IF formula around the numbers.

```
=INT(MID(O2,1,1))
```

Comment: Brilliant, no matter how much I learn about Excel there's always a bit more